# PCF p-config-server /decrypt api returning 403 forbidden error

Tags: spring-cloud, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-config

While trying to use encryption/decryption feature of spring cloud config server with Pivotal Cloud Foundry's p-config-server service  which is configured with a symmetric key for encryption, I am getting a 403 forbidden response which calling /decrypt on config server .

I am able to call the /encrypt endpoint successfully for encrypting values using below sample curl -

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://config-xxxx.apps.xxx.com/encrypt' \
--header 'Authorization: bearer <cf oauth_token here>' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
--data-raw 'sample data'
```

But when trying to decrypt those values using /decrypt, I am getting 403 Forbidden error -

```
{
"error": "access_denied",
"error_description": "invalid issuer"
}
```

Sample curl for decryption -

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://config-xxxx.apps.xxx.com/decrypt' \
--header 'Authorization: bearer <cf oauth_token here>' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
--data-raw '<encrypted value from previous step>'
```

In pivotal's config server documentation though there are reference to /encrypt but nothing related to /decrypt [pivotal config server](https://docs.pivotal.io/spring-cloud-services/3-1/common/config-server/configuring-with-git.html)

Any pointers ?

Comment: Have you talked to your support contract? PCF p-config-server isn't supported here

Answer (score 0):

In the Pivotal/Tanzu Spring Cloud Services (commercial product), the `/encrypt` API is exposed to anyone with the admin scope or to anyone that is a Space Developer in the space of the service.

The `/decrypt` endpoint is not exposed specifically, so you're not allowed to access with the same credentials, hence why you're seeing a 403.

My quick read of the code is that you'd need a token with scope `config_server_<guide>.read` to access that endpoint. Where `<guid>` is the config server's service guide (run `cf service --guid <name>` to obtain the guide).

To make that work, you'd need to get a token from the bound service or a service key, the latter is easier:

1. Run `cf create-service-key <service_instance> decrypt-key`
2. Run `cf service-key <service_instance> decrypt-key`
3. Run `export TOKEN=$(curl -vv <access_token_uri> -d 'grant_type=client_credentials' -d 'client_id=<client_id>' -d 'client_secret=<client_secret>' | jq -r .access_token)` where the values in `<...>` are from the output of #2.
4. Run `curl -vv '<uri>/decrypt' -H "Authorization: bearer $TOKEN" -H 'Content-type: text/plain' -d '<encrypted-value>'`

These depend on a Bash shell. You can do them on Windows, but the commands will vary. It also uses `jq` to make extracting the token easier. You could split the command in step #3 into two steps, fetching with `curl` and manually exporting TOKEN.

Comment: i was able to pass security check this approach but now I am getting a 404 error while calling the decrypt route.  Is this disabled by default? how can we enable it ??  404 error i am getting is - `{
    "timestamp": "2020-12-08T09:17:41.124+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "Disabled",
    "path": "/decrypt"
}`

Comment: It's there, it worked fine when I tested it. I tested with SCS 3.1, but I don't recall the specific version. Make sure you're using 3.1.x.

Comment: we are on SCS 2.1 - is it not supported on that version?

Comment: If you perform the steps above and get a 404 when trying to access `/decrypt`, then yes. Sounds like it's not supported on that version & you need to upgrade.